# Creating a Jquery function that can tell if a YouTube channel is live

Tags: jquery, json, server, youtube, youtube-api

I am new to using Server requests so I appreciate any help:

I am working on a page that hosts YouTube streams for church service, I am trying to write code that looks at the YouTube channel, and lets me know if the YouTube stream is live.

Is there an existing API or JSON file that i can use to find this information, or would i need to create a server Get request then parse the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those approaching the same issue, here is the solution I found.

You have to create an API key on google clouds platform, and use that key in this URL, along with the Channel ID you want to check if it is live:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=[CHANNELID]&type=video&eventType=live&key=[APIKEY]

Please note that you only have a limited amount of requests per day on this API, so use them sparingly!